# Removing a field from jSon String

Tags: c#, json

I am storing jSon string as hexa-decimal or some characters string, its all working fine whan I retrieving as json string in my code, but there is one field I want to remove from the jSob object after I retrieved.

```
  var t = StoredProcedures.SP_GlobalSearch.Execute(new SP_GlobalSearch_Params
                    {
                        Search = request.search,
                        SourceKey = "",
                        Skip = start,
                        Take = length,
                        ShowDeleted = false
                    }).Select(x => new SP_GlobalSearch
                    {
                        JsonObject = x.Data != null ? new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(x.Data.Replace("ï»¿", "")) : null,
                        Date = x.Date,
                        JsonObjectId = x.JsonObjectId,
                        SourceKey = x.SourceKey,
                        SourceId = x.SourceId,
                        TotalCount = x.TotalCount
                    });

                    var response = t?.ToList();

                    var jsondata = new DataTableResponse<SP_GlobalSearch>
                    {
                        totalCount = (int)response.Where(x => x.TotalCount != null).FirstOrDefault().TotalCount,
                        data = response.Where(x => x.TotalCount == null)
                    };

                    var jsonResult = Json(jsondata);
                    jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
                    return jsonResult;
```

I am reading the text as jSon with the below statement,

```
JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(x.Data.Replace("ï»¿", ""))
```

I want to remove the violations field from it, any help please. Thanks in advance

Here is my json:

```
{
   "InspectionResultId":846,
   "InspectionResultNumber":"T00846",
   "InspectionRequestId":507,
   "InspectionRequestNumber":"R00507",
   "CaseId":689,
   "InspectionResultStatusId":605,
   "EnforcementSectionId":104,
   "ViolationTypeId":603,
   "DateOfInspection":"\/Date(1589439600000)\/",
   "InspectionComment":"send to office staff, open investigation",
   "InspectedCompanyDataId":964,
   "ContactTypeId":701,
   "EnteredById":"7f54fa3e-b5cd-4b2e-9490-92f64c022246",
   "InspectionResultTimestamp":"\/Date(1588280817470)\/",
   "DateCreated":"\/Date(1588280817487)\/",
   "DateUpdated":"\/Date(1588281867967)\/",
   "CreatedByUserId":"7f54fa3e-b5cd-4b2e-9490-92f64c022246",
   "UpdatedByUserId":"7f54fa3e-b5cd-4b2e-9490-92f64c022246",
   "Case":{
      "RelatedContactId":0,
      "CaseId":689,
      "CaseNumber":"I00689",
      "IsInvestigation":true,
      "CaseStatusId":801,
      "InspectionItemSourceId":211,
      "EnforcementSectionId":104,
      "ReminderDate":"\/Date(1590044400000)\/",
      "PreCaseSummary":"send to office staff, open investigation",
      "AssignedToInspectorId":"7f54fa3e-b5cd-4b2e-9490-92f64c022246",
      "CaseTimestamp":"\/Date(1588281867403)\/",
      "CaseCompanyId":964,
      "DateCreated":"\/Date(1588281867437)\/",
      "DateUpdated":"\/Date(1588281867840)\/",
      "CreatedByUserId":"7f54fa3e-b5cd-4b2e-9490-92f64c022246",
      "UpdatedByUserId":"7f54fa3e-b5cd-4b2e-9490-92f64c022246",
      "IsDeleted":false,
      "InterpreterNeeded":false,
      "VoluntaryDisclosure":false,
      "PenaltyAdjustment":0,
      "Company":{
         "ContactId":964,
         "ContactTypeId":1000,
         "FirstName":"04.30.2020 new co",
         "Notes":"new request",
         "Active":true,
         "Created":"\/Date(1588279909680)\/",
         "Updated":"\/Date(1588279909680)\/",
         "DateCreated":"\/Date(1588279909680)\/",
         "DateUpdated":"\/Date(1588279909680)\/",
         "IsEJArea":false,
         "CreatedByUserId":"7f54fa3e-b5cd-4b2e-9490-92f64c022246",
         "UpdatedByUserId":"7f54fa3e-b5cd-4b2e-9490-92f64c022246",
         "Classification":{

         },
         "Class":"Company",
         "IsSpecial":false,
         "Address":{
            "Street1":"5678 Street",
            "City":"Sacramento",
            "StateCode":"CA",
            "Zip":"95812",
            "Country":"0"
         }
      }
   },
   "InspectionResultStatus":{
      "InspectionResultStatusId":605,
      "InspectionResultStatusName":"Clean",
      "InspectionResultStatusSortOrder":5
   },
   "EnforcementSection":{
      "EnforcementSectionId":104,
      "EnforcementSectionName":"STBES",
      "EnforcementSectionSortOrder":0,
      "BranchId":2
   },
   "InspectedCompanyData":{
      "ContactId":964,
      "ContactTypeId":1000,
      "FirstName":"04.30.2020 new co",
      "Notes":"new request",
      "Active":true,
      "Created":"\/Date(1588279909680)\/",
      "Updated":"\/Date(1588279909680)\/",
      "DateCreated":"\/Date(1588279909680)\/",
      "DateUpdated":"\/Date(1588279909680)\/",
      "IsEJArea":false,
      "CreatedByUserId":"7f54fa3e-b5cd-4b2e-9490-92f64c022246",
      "UpdatedByUserId":"7f54fa3e-b5cd-4b2e-9490-92f64c022246",
      "Classification":{

      },
      "Class":"Company",
      "IsSpecial":false
   },
   "InspectionItems":[
      {
         "InspectionItemId":1054,
         "InspectionItemNumber":"T00000",
         "InspectionRequestId":507,
         "InspectionResultId":846,
         "CaseId":689,
         "InspectionItemSourceId":229,
         "IsCreatedInCase":false,
         "ShowYearMakeModel":"",
         "ShowYearMakeModelVIN":"",
         "GrossWeight":0.00,
         "RegHoldSet":false,
         "InspectionItemTimestamp":"\/Date(1588280802553)\/",
         "DateCreated":"\/Date(1588280802567)\/",
         "DateUpdated":"\/Date(1588281868153)\/",
         "CreatedByUserId":"7f54fa3e-b5cd-4b2e-9490-92f64c022246",
         "UpdatedByUserId":"7f54fa3e-b5cd-4b2e-9490-92f64c022246",
         "Violations":[

         ]
      }
   ],
   "CompletedBy":[
      {
         "IsActive":true,
         "FirstName":"Daphne",
         "LastName":"Greene",
         "ObjectGUID":"S-1-5-21-1538631513-416410304-3002070310-33442",
         "NameLoginFormat":"dgreene",
         "NameFirstLast":"Daphne Greene",
         "NameLastFirst":"Greene Daphne",
         "Email":"daphne.greene@arb.ca.gov",
         "EmailConfirmed":false,
         "SecurityStamp":"e061e77e-c93e-4b9e-8497-4852b5cb4ca2",
         "PhoneNumberConfirmed":false,
         "TwoFactorEnabled":false,
         "LockoutEnabled":false,
         "AccessFailedCount":0,
         "Id":"7f54fa3e-b5cd-4b2e-9490-92f64c022246",
         "UserName":"dgreene"
      }
   ],
   "EnteredBy":{
      "IsActive":true,
      "FirstName":"Daphne",
      "LastName":"Greene",
      "ObjectGUID":"S-1-5-21-1538631513-416410304-3002070310-33442",
      "NameLoginFormat":"dgreene",
      "NameFirstLast":"Daphne Greene",
      "NameLastFirst":"Greene Daphne",
      "Email":"daphne.greene@arb.ca.gov",
      "EmailConfirmed":false,
      "SecurityStamp":"e061e77e-c93e-4b9e-8497-4852b5cb4ca2",
      "PhoneNumberConfirmed":false,
      "TwoFactorEnabled":false,
      "LockoutEnabled":false,
      "AccessFailedCount":0,
      "Id":"7f54fa3e-b5cd-4b2e-9490-92f64c022246",
      "UserName":"dgreene"
   },
   "MyGridContacts":[

   ],
   "CreatedByUser":{
      "IsActive":true,
      "FirstName":"Daphne",
      "LastName":"Greene",
      "ObjectGUID":"S-1-5-21-1538631513-416410304-3002070310-33442",
      "NameLoginFormat":"dgreene",
      "NameFirstLast":"Daphne Greene",
      "NameLastFirst":"Greene Daphne",
      "Email":"daphne.greene@arb.ca.gov",
      "EmailConfirmed":false,
      "SecurityStamp":"e061e77e-c93e-4b9e-8497-4852b5cb4ca2",
      "PhoneNumberConfirmed":false,
      "TwoFactorEnabled":false,
      "LockoutEnabled":false,
      "AccessFailedCount":0,
      "Id":"7f54fa3e-b5cd-4b2e-9490-92f64c022246",
      "UserName":"dgreene"
   },
   "UpdatedByUser":{
      "IsActive":true,
      "FirstName":"Daphne",
      "LastName":"Greene",
      "ObjectGUID":"S-1-5-21-1538631513-416410304-3002070310-33442",
      "NameLoginFormat":"dgreene",
      "NameFirstLast":"Daphne Greene",
      "NameLastFirst":"Greene Daphne",
      "Email":"daphne.greene@arb.ca.gov",
      "EmailConfirmed":false,
      "SecurityStamp":"e061e77e-c93e-4b9e-8497-4852b5cb4ca2",
      "PhoneNumberConfirmed":false,
      "TwoFactorEnabled":false,
      "LockoutEnabled":false,
      "AccessFailedCount":0,
      "Id":"7f54fa3e-b5cd-4b2e-9490-92f64c022246",
      "UserName":"dgreene"
   }
}
```

This above object is a dynamic object returned as string I want to remove Violation related fields and its values from it.
I want to remove the Violations, ViolationTypeId etc fields related to Violation from the jSon object above, can you please help me in this regards thank you.

Comment: I think it would be easier to show us the output of the json also.

Comment: *I want to remove the violations field from it* - how can we tell you how to do that without seeing the JSON itself?  If you were to [edit] your question to include a [mcve] it's much more likely somebody here can help you.  See: [ask].

Comment: Hi I have added the jSong sample string to original post by editing - thank you for your response.

Comment: Why are you using `JavaScriptSerializer` which is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8) by Microsoft?  Why not [tag:json.net] or [tag:system.text.json]?

Comment: I am not sure can you please help me little more about this and its a dynamic object changed how can I remove the Violations and ViolationTypeId etc fields from the above jSon please

Answer (score 1):

You can simply convert it to object, remove the field and back to string.

for example in javascript

assuming your json is in variable myjson

```
tmp = Object(myjson.Data)
delete tmp.Violations
myjson.Data = JSON.stringify(tmp)
```

in C#, assuming Data is your string json

```
JObject tmp = JObject.Parse(Data);
tmp.Property("Violations").Remove();
Data = JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(jsonResult.Data);
```

Comment: I want to remove it in C# can I

Comment: Thank you Love You bro

Comment: Happy to help brother ! you may mark it as answered ✅ if this answer helped you.